# how to plot segmented barchart for diferrent groups vs binary data?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, binary-data

I have a dataset df and I want to plot a segmented bar chart for every unique ID vs the binary values in the column Bin. So in the, I will have one column for each ID, divided in two parts for the different values in the Bin column (0,1)

```
dput(df)
structure(list(ο.ΏID = c("F1", "F1", "F1", "F1", "F1", "F1", 
"F1", "F2", "F2", "F2", "F2", "F2", "F2", "F2", "F2", "F3", "F3", 
"F3", "F3", "F3", "F3", "F3", "F3", "F3", "F4", "F4", "F4", "F4", 
"F4", "F4", "F4", "F4"), Date = c("22/6/2021", "23/6/2021", "24/6/2021", 
"25/6/2021", "26/6/2021", "27/6/2021", "28/6/2021", "22/6/2021", 
"23/6/2021", "24/6/2021", "25/6/2021", "26/6/2021", "27/6/2021", 
"28/6/2021", "29/6/2021", "22/6/2021", "23/6/2021", "24/6/2021", 
"25/6/2021", "26/6/2021", "27/6/2021", "28/6/2021", "29/6/2021", 
"30/6/2021", "22/6/2021", "23/6/2021", "24/6/2021", "25/6/2021", 
"26/6/2021", "27/6/2021", "28/6/2021", "29/6/2021"), Values = c(9.6, 
9.8, 10.2, 9.8, 9.9, 9.9, 9.9, 1.2, 1.2, 1.8, 1.5, 1.5, 1.6, 
1.4, 1.1, 3266, 3256, 7044, 6868, 6556, 3405, 3410, 3980, 5567, 
59.4, 56, 52.8, 52.4, 55.5, 54, 61, 53.6), Bin = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-32L))
```

this is what I have done so far

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = ID, y = Bin, fill = Bin )) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +facet_wrap(~ID, scales = 'free')
```

Comment: The column 'Bin' is numeric.  you may change it to factor i.e. `df$Bin <- factor(df$Bin)` and apply the code.  I guess `y = Values` i.e. `ggplot(data = df, aes(x = ID, y = Values, fill = Bin )) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +facet_wrap(~ID, scales = 'free')`

Comment: In your data for each ID for each Bin there are multiple values for different dates, do you want the date to be your x-axis or you want to discard it and sum the values?

Comment: what akrun suggested above is exactly what i wanted. But do you have any suggestion of how I can include the date in all that?  @NaremanDarwish

Comment: Depends on the business case but it can be something like that ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Date, y = Values, fill = factor(Bin))) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge()) +
  facet_wrap(~ID, scales = 'free') +
  labs(fill = "Bin")